# Added 2nd HDD, created new mount point for /mnt/datanew, get you are not the owner

Tags: partitioning, mountpoint

I am completely new to Linux and have been asked to extend a VM running Ubuntu, I thought I would test this first so have just installed it in a  test VM, I added the 2nd hard drive and used Gparted to format it with ext4 so I now have a drive called /dev/sdb1

I then created a new directory called mnt/datanew

I then mounted that using the below command

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/datanew
```

I thought I was doing well until when I went into home folder / file system mnt / datanew I noticed I couldn't create a new folder etc, I check the properties and it said I don't have permission as its all root

How do I change this, I need to create some data and then test extending the partition as I want to see if it has any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to tell the system you are the owner of the mount point. So when logged in with your user do ($USER will be automagically changed to your user name):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/datanew
```

Comment: Not try ... do ;) Try makes it a comment :D I also added changing the group ;)

Comment: Many Thanks, that worked one more question I have is that when I click on Home folders my new drive shows up  under floppy drive as a device, is that correct?

Comment: @user212383 Can you provide a screenshot of that?